# retrieves specific values from a matrix

Tags: python

I have data that looks like that :

```
array = 
[[1, 2019, done]
[1,2019 , undone]
...
[1, 2018, done]
[1, nan, done]
[2, 2017, undone]]
```

I want to retrieve all the dates that have a value only one time, and the number of "done" for each date in lists.

I tried to get the results I wanted parsing the data.

```
date, counter= [], []

for i in range (len(array)):
    if array[i][1] not in date and array[i][1]!="":
        date.append(array[i][1])

for j in range(len(X)):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if X[j] == array[i][1] and array[i][2] == "done":
            count +=1
    counter.append(count)
```

I currently have a list of date with repeated values and a lot of "nan" values too
X = [2019,2019,2019,nan,nan,nan, 2017 ...]

I want to get something that looks like that
date =[2019,2018,2017...]
counter=[200, 150,100,...]

Comment: if this is the data [ [1,2019, done], [1, 2019, done], [1, 2019, undone] , [1, nan, done], [1, nan, undone]] What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have the following data:

```py
done = "done"
undone = "undone"
nan = "nan"

array = [[1, 2019, done],
         [1, 2019, undone],
         [1, 2018, done],
         [1, nan, done],
         [2, 2017, undone]]
```

To select only dates that have a year, do can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
selection = [[m, y, f] for m, y, f in array if y != nan]
```

You get:

```py
[[1, 2019, 'done'],
 [1, 2019, 'undone'],
 [1, 2018, 'done'],
 [2, 2017, 'undone']]
```

To count the number of "done", you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
groups = collections.Counter()
for month, year, flag in selection:
    if flag == done:
        groups[(month, year)] += 1
```

You get:

```py
Counter({(1, 2019): 1, (1, 2018): 1})
```